# I want to hide Dragging rows count and Drop status text

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I'm making Drag and drop between Datagrid now.

I nearly succeed but I got one problem when I Dragging one Row.

This status text following cursor in the Datagrid area.

I want to hide this:

[image: I want hide this.]

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
this.sfDataGrid.RowDragDropController.DragOver += RowDragDropController_DragOver;

private void RowDragDropController_DragOver(object sender, GridRowDragOverEventArgs e) {
    e.ShowDragUI = false;
}
```

Could you give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using Syncfusion controls.

We have checked your requirement at our end, when disable the e.ShowDragUI in SfDataGrid.DragOver event and the popup is disabled. So, could you please check the below sample and video location,

Code Example:

```
this.dataGrid1.RowDragDropController.DragOver += RowDragDropController_DragOver;  

private void RowDragDropController_DragOver(object sender, Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridRowDragOverEventArgs e)  
{  
  e.ShowDragUI = false;  
}
```

Sample Link:  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DragDropDemo-309709895

UG Link:  https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/datagrid/drag-and-drop#disable-the-default-drag-ui

Video Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DragDropDataGrid-1321231392

If still you are facing the same issue, please revert us with more details on replication procedure/video illustration of the issue. Also, if possible, please revert us with the modified sample. It will help us to investigate further and provide earlier prompt solution.

Regards,
Saravanan A

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried but I got " Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'GridRowDragOverEventArgs' does not exist in the namespace 'Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid' " this message. which one should I add to Reference?